# TestRestTemplate throws exception for 4xx status codes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, resttemplate, spring-boot-test

I am writing component tests for a Spring-Boot application, to test my security configuration. I am therefore running tests that should test for both successful responses as well as "forbidden" status.
The problem I'm encountering is that because my REST call expects a complex JSON, for blocked calls the tests fail because TestRestTemplate is trying to deserialize a response body that is not there.

I am running a Spring-Boot application, and the tests class is annotated with:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
```

I am trying to test a REST API that should return a list of users.
A simplified version of the call would be:

```
ResponseEntity<List<User>> responseEntity  = testRestTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<User>>() {});
```

where the TestRestTemplate is autowired by Spring, and the entity contains the authorization information.

For unauthorized request, I am getting an error like:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [java.util.List<my.package.User>] and content type [application/json;charset=UTF-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 1]
```

If I change the response entity to receive String instead of List, I receive the response and can check the status and see that it is "forbidden"

```
ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity  = testRestTemplate.exchange(URL, HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
```

I know I can work around this by:

- Using String and deserializing with Gson, or
- Using RestTemplate instead of TestRestTemplate and handling the HttpStatusCodeException, or
- Overriding methods to not try to deserialize when status code is not 2xx

but since TestRestTemplate is supposed to be a fault-tolerant convenience subclass, I would have expected it to out-of-the-box not try to deserialize on error response.

Am I missing something here? Am I using it wrong?

Comment: >2 years later and this is a problem for me as well. You would expect that the `TestRestTemplate` would not try to deserialize an Error into the complex object if that HttpResponse was not 200...

Answer (score 1):

I expect that implementing a `ResponseErrorHandler` could help you work-around this.

But for **RestTemplate** it's the default behavior to throw errors on non-success results, are you sure you did not yet override it? Maybe you could use a dedicated `RestTemplate` for your test.

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/HttpClientErrorException.html

> Exception thrown when an HTTP 4xx is received.

For implementing a `ResponseErrorHandler`, see https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-error-handling

**EDIT**: Indeed for **TestRestTemplate** this is not default behavior its meant for integration tests with the following benefits:

> the template behaves in a test-friendly way by not throwing exceptions on server-side errors
>   ...
>
> - Redirects are not followed (so you can assert the response location).
> - Cookies are ignored (so the template is stateless).

In your case you promise in your test code that a list of users is returned while this is not true, I would not expect the code to be resilient against that, I would even say that for that case a `RestTemplate` might make more sense.

Comment: Using **RestTemplate** - yes. Exceptions are the default and expected behavior for errors. However, I'm trying to use **TestRestTemplate**, where the expected behavior, at least to my understanding, is supposed to handle the exceptions for your tests, but is not thoroughly defined.
Specifically: if you run a query that parses the response to String, TestRestTemplate wraps it properly and handles the exception for you. If you change the expected response from String to a complex class, I get an error parsing the response.
You can see the examples I provided in the original post for reference.

Comment: Ok, then I do believe you are using it wrong. Because the TestRestTemplate is indeed not meant to say you need a List of users while nothing is returned in case of an error, that is just an invalid state in your test. If you need the behaviour to validate 200 response or not, you are better of with a normal `RestTemplate` and some `ExpectedException` `Rule`.

Comment: I only now realize your question is six months old, how did you solve it in the end :-)

Comment: I must respectfully disagree. To my understanding, an implementation that is specialized for testing (integration or otherwise) is expected to properly handle errors and failures - as this is what these tests are expected to catch. TestRestTemplate already returns the relevant error status code in a convenient way, my problem with the existing implementation is that I do not understand why it still tries to convert the response to the expected result type when the status is not successful.

Comment: In the end, due to time restrictions, my solution was to return String values, assert the status code to make sure if successful or not, and convert the string to the expected type when successful for further asserts. I didn't have too many tests, so performance-wise it was a decent compromise.
For similar situations in the future, I will probably look into alternative REST clients.

Comment: Using **TestRestTemplate** helped solve my problem with throwing exceptions

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for resurrecting this almost 2-year-old question, but I ran into a very similar problem while working with Spring `TestRestTemplate` and negative validation tests.

As Martin mentioned in his answer, `TestRestTemplate` does not include the `ResponseErrorHandler` that is normally associated with the proper `RestTemplate`.  But the body of the response will still contain an error message instead of a list of `User`.

In my case, my web-app had `@ControllerAdvice` that wrapped all the common validation errors (`MethodArgumentNotValidException`, `MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException`, etc) and returned an instance of my own class `ErrorMessageDto`.  The controller will marshal that to JSON instead of the expected response.

My component test initially tried to catch `HttpStatusCodeException` because that is thrown by the normal `RestTemplate`.  In the test, the exception was not thrown (because of the lack of `ResponseErrorHandler`) and my `restTemplate.postForObject(path, request, MyResponse.class)` simply returned an empty version of `MyResponse`.

After reading Martin's description and following links, I changed it to

```
ResponseEntity<ErrorMessageDto> responseEntity = restTemplate.postForEntity(path, request, ErrorMessageDto.class);

// Do assertions on the response code and body (using assertj)
assertThat(responseEntity.getStatusCode()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY);
assertThat(responseEntity.getBody().getErrors())
                .extracting("path", "message")
                .contains(tuple("firstName", "size must be between 0 and 255"))
```

In your case, I am sure the error message you are returning is an instance of an error message class.  You probably realized this with your suggestion of returning a String and marshalling manually.  If you know what class your error message is representing, you can simply replace that as the type in your `ResponseEntity`.